# Why pavucontrol does not save the recording device permanently?

Tags: pulseaudio, monitoring, alsa, chrome, streaming

I'm doing recording tests for my streaming, I have enabled and as default "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo", in old versions of chrome it works perfect, but in the new ones I have to change from "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" to "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" to work, the problem is that I have to do this every time, when i open a new tab or every time if restart the browser, is there a way not to have to do this repeatedly and save this permanent change?

**from this:**

[image]

**to this:**

[image]

**Any way to make "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" as default in Recording tab for any application, Completely permanent?**

Answer (score 0):

First, `pavucontrol` is just an UI for Pulseaudio, `pavucontrol` doesn't set anything by itself.

Second, Pulseaudio is normally configured to remember sources and sinks **per application**, and if you start an application a second time, it will use those sources and sinks, unless they are not available. The "default source" or "default sink" is only used if this doesn't work for some reason (because it's the first time, or because it is not available).

So if this restore feature of Pulseaudio doesn't work for you, you need to debug your Pulseaudio configuration, or debug why the new Chrome doesn't work with (for example, if it changes the application name on every restart).